# Models in Packages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My package requires models, but I get a class not found error why I try and do:

```
MyModel::all();
```

My models folder is under src and in my composer.json file i have:

```
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/migrations",
        "src/models"
    ],
```

I have also run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Here's my model file:

```
<?php

class MyModel extends Eloquent {


}
```

Do I need to namespace the model the same as my package?

Comment: Are you using the workbench? If so, then you need to dump-autoload through artisan: `php artisan dump-autoload'. Or did you forgot to add the `use your/namespace/MyModel;` at the top of the file where you want to use the model?

Comment: I've done both, still fails. Where should my model be exactly, file structure wise? Inside MyCorp/MyPackage/src/Models or MyCorp/MyPackage/src/MyCorp/MyPackage/Models

Comment: Doesn't matter because you're using `classmap` and not `psr-4`. If you run the `composer dump-autoload` then composer creates a classmap that registers your model: `'MyNameSpace\\MyModel' => $vendorDir . '/MyCorp/MyPackage/src/Models/MyModel.php', ..` inside the file: `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more clearly, thanks!

Comment: Where did you call your `MyModel::all()` method? And in package development namespacing is almost necessary in any case. So essentially, yes to your question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all package classes should be namespaced and you should know how PHP namespaces work. I recommend composer psr-4 autoloading for this.

Second, you need to use the fully qualified class names instead of the global namespace aliases. `Eloquent` is actually `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. You can find all the aliases in your `app/config/app.php` file.